# How to stop Glide loading Image over and over again when scrolling in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide

I'm using Glide v3.8.0 (not v4) to load Image in to ImageView in an item of RecyclerView, and there is a bit problems: every time scroll the RecyclerView up or down, Glide load the Image into ImageView that already been loaded before, and the bad result is scroll is not smooth because it keep reload Image every time I scroll to, I don't want to reload an image that completely loaded. I have found some same questions but still have no right answer to this problem

This is my code to load image into RecyclerView item

```
    Glide.with(mContext).load(function.BitmapToByte(function.GetBitmap(currSong.getData())))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).error(R.drawable.noteicon).into(holder.coverimg);
```

Comment: can you post your adapter code?

Comment: "reload image" like load from cache or load from network?

Comment: reload from cache, those are embedded images of audio file, i don't load from url network

Comment: Hi. Do you fixed your problem?

Comment: @HuyThang Do you fixed your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try load it by file name 
Use something like string varible so let glide know that the same image loaded before

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and i fixed it using

```
recyclerview.setItemViewCacheSize(50);
```

This way not all old items will be recycled